# org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist:

Tags: apache-spark

I'm a newbie in using apache spark. I'm trying to do a simple example with it on window 10 as following:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

val txtFile = "README.md"

val txtData = sc.textFile(txtFile)

txtData.cache()

val wcData = txtData.flatMap(l => l.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

After the last command, it gives me an error like that:

> ```
> scala> val wcData = txtData.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
> org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/D:/Spark/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/input.txt
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:287)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:229)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:200)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
>   at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:46)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
>   at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:46)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
>   at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:46)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
>   at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:251)
>   at org.apache.spark.Partitioner$$anonfun$4.apply(Partitioner.scala:78)
>   at org.apache.spark.Partitioner$$anonfun$4.apply(Partitioner.scala:78)
>   at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>   at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>   at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
>   at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
>   at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
>   at org.apache.spark.Partitioner$.defaultPartitioner(Partitioner.scala:78)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$reduceByKey$3.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:326)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$reduceByKey$3.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:326)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
>   at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.reduceByKey(PairRDDFunctions.scala:325)
>   ... 51 elided
> ```

I have no idea about this exception. Please give me a help or whatever you think about it.
Thank you.

Comment: Well, what about reading the error message? `Input path does not exist: file:/D:/Spark/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/input.txt` - I'm pretty sure that this is not the code that you're trying to run on Spark given that in the shown code here you load a `README.md` - so, how and what are you running on the Spark standalone cluster? I mean, you have to build some `jar` file and use it during execution? OR do you use the shell?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using spark shell

Comment: I think your code and your error message are not consistent, please update question. And by the way, if you are using `spark-shell` the file `val txtFile = "README.md" should be existed in the directory you call `spark-shell`, in this case, you called it in `D:/Spark/spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/`. To work with file, it is better to use absolute path as hard coded in your code, or get file path as application parameter.

Comment: @NgọcSơnĐỗ the code shown here still does **not** match the error message. It clearly states that a file `input.txt` isn't found but you're code never loads such a file but a file named `README.md`. And use absolute paths. A general comment, please don't copy and paste things without understanding what it does. that's not how you learn Spark API nor programming at all